# Strange behaviour of golang exec.Command program

Tags: go

I have such code:

```
func main() {
        s := "foobar"
        cmd := exec.Command("wc", "-l")
        stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
        if err != nil {
                log.Panic(err)
        }
        stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
        if err != nil {
                log.Panic(err)
        }
        err = cmd.Start()
        if err != nil {
                log.Panic(err)
        }
        io.Copy(stdin, bytes.NewBufferString(s))
        stdin.Close()
        io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)
        err = cmd.Wait()
        if err != nil {
                log.Panic(err)
        }
}
```

and its output is:

`0`

But when I will do simple modification:

```
func main() {
        runWcFromStdinWorks("aaa\n")
        runWcFromStdinWorks("bbb\n")
}

func runWcFromStdinWorks(s string) {
        cmd := exec.Command("wc", "-l")
        stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
        if err != nil {
                log.Panic(err)
        }
        stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
        if err != nil {
                log.Panic(err)
        }
        err = cmd.Start()
        if err != nil {
                log.Panic(err)
        }
        io.Copy(stdin, bytes.NewBufferString(s))
        stdin.Close()
        io.Copy(os.Stdout, stdout)
        err = cmd.Wait()
        if err != nil {
                log.Panic(err)
        }
}
```

It works, but why? Its just calling method why first version is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string `s` in the first example does not have a new line, which causes `wc -l` to return 0. You can see this behavior by doing:

```
$ echo -n hello | wc -l
0
```